# does any non-empty finite subset of a set have a minimal element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(A,\sqsubseteq)$ be a partially ordered set and $\emptyset\neq B\subset A$ a finite subset. Does $B$ have a minimal element (with repect to to $\sqsubseteq$)?

I want to prove this by induction, but I get stuck at the induction hypotheses. Is this the easiest ways to prove this, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

If there's one element, then you're done: it is a minimal element.

Suppose the proposition holds for $n \geq 1$ elements.

Given a finite subset of $n+1$ elements, first order any $n$ of them to find a minimal element, i.e., apply the Induction Hypothesis to $n$ of them. Then compare the element you've found to the last element in the subset of $n+1$ elements; this will give you a minimal element, though you may wish to write out a few more details in this regard.

Then the proposition holds for any finite subset by the Principle of Mathematical Induction.

Comment: You do not necessarily have a *smallest* element (that is, an element smaller than all the others), all you can claim is that there are *minimal* elements (that is, with no elements strictly smaller). To fix the argument: Given $n+1$ elements, pick $n$. By induction, that set has a minimal element (not necessarily a smallest). Now consider the set consisting of that minimal element $a$, and the remaining ($n+1$-st) element. If either is smaller than the other, it is then minimal for the whole set of $n+1$ elements. If neither is smaller than the other, then $a$ is minimal.

Comment: Right: I will change the word "smallest" to "minimal"; thanks for pointing out the distinction.